# Como passar o nome da(s) planilhas Excel para uma JList

Tags: java, microsoft-excel

Gostaria de saber como eu passo os nomes das planilhas de uma pasta de trabalho de excel para uma JList quando clico em um botão.
Sendo que já tenho o botão criado e ele simula uma Shell para localizar o arquivo.

Aproveitando o tópico, tenho como capturar o nome do arquivo que estarei abrindo e passar para um JTextField ou outro componente?